# Error when confirming Devise user while using cancancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancancan, devise-confirmable

Following the confirm link in the email that gets sent for a user signup gives this error:

```
uninitialized constant Confirmation 
NameError in Devise::ConfirmationsController#show
```

But if I turn off `Cancancan` by removing `load_and_authorize_resource` in the `ApplicationController`, the error doesn't happen and the user can successfully follow the confirm link.

I've tried adding `skip_load_and_authorize_resource` in an overrided Devise controller for the Confirmations-- `Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController`.

[image]

Comment: Can you add some more lines of stacktrace? So that we can analyse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possibilities according to your explanation are:

1. The reason of `uninitialized constant Confirmation` might be that it is trying to find out the model associated with this controller using the controller name and the result it gets is `Confirmation` but there is no model with that name.
2. The `skip_load_and_authorize_resource` might not work until you have the `show` action in your overrided controller itself (adding a before action on child class should not work on parent class I think)

I am not sure if this will work or not but you can try something like this and see in your `ApplicationController`:

```
load_and_authorize_resource unless: :devise_controller?
```

So this will skip that `before_action` for all devise controllers.

Comment: Thanks! Doing the unless: :devise_controller? worked, but I changed to unless: :confirmations_controller? because some devise controllers need to follow some rules of cancancann (which are in the abilities.rb) -- such as updating a user/profile.

I'm interested in the first idea you had-- I wish I could skip it in the actual controller.  But I added in the show action and still didn't work.  Also i had done the same (added skip_load_and_authorize_resource) in another devise controller at an earlier date and it worked in bypassing it without having any actions defined in the class. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to confirm have you used the same controllers in the routes file something like this: `devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}`, I guess after this it should work.

Comment: That was it!  After adding that back in the routes file, only putting skip_load_and_authorize_resource in the overrided ConfirmationsController fixed the error (didn't need to have the show action defined).  Thanks a ton, Deep.

Answer (score 0):

The `load_and_authorize_resource` shouldn’t be used in the `ApplicationController`, because it is not compatible with the devices and controllers that do not have models with the same name. Instead, set `load_and_authorize_resource` in each controller as needed.